# How to display Chinese in PDF generated by weasyprint?

Tags: python, weasyprint

I try to set the font, but it still fails.

**Python**

```
from weasyprint import HTML, CSS
from weasyprint.fonts import FontConfiguration

font_config = FontConfiguration()

stylesheets=[CSS('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Noto+Sans+TC'), CSS("sample.css", font_config=font_config)]

html.write_pdf("test.pdf", stylesheets=stylesheets)
```

**CSS**

```
body {
  font-family: 'Noto Sans TC', '微軟正黑體', sans-serif;
  font-display: swap;
}
```

[PDF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z5BGu.png)

I hope that traditional Chinese can be displayed normally.

Comment: What does the HTML look like? Is it UTF-8 encoded? Does it contain `<meta charset="utf-8">`?

Comment: Yes, I have used meta, the HTML is as follows.
```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>


 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
 <link href="http://localhost:8001/static/invoice.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <title>Index</title>

 <style>
  .page-break {
   page-break-after: always;
  }
 </style>

</head>

<body>


 <div class="invoice container">
  <div class="section top-left">
   <p>收件人：</p>
   <p>送貨地址：XXXXXX</p>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="page-break"></div>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It just adds this, I don't even need to set fonts in weasyprint.

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Noto+Sans+TC:wght@400;500;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Comment: Sorry ... but your self-answer doesn't make sense.  *"It just adds this ..."* - **what** just adds that?  A self-answer question is only useful to other people if they can understand the question, the answer and (in this case) how the answer solves the problem described by the question.

Comment: Also ... you should put the extra details that you added in comments above into the question itself.  Use the EDIT button ...